# Cookie management in PhoneGap applications - Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I don't understand how Phonegap manages cookies within a web application? how it encapsulates the Android CookieManager? I'm trying to manipulate a cookie via Javascript but navigator.cookie seems to be not supported within a Phonegap Application.

Thanks

```
function deleteCookie ( name, path, domain ) {
        document.cookie = name + "=" +
        ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
        ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
        ";expires="+(new Date()).toGMTString();
}

deleteCookie( "MY_COOKIE_NAME", "/", "mydomain.com" );
```